# Failed to resolve "java.lang.ArrayStoreException"

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing code for a small monster game based on 2DArray. But I can't proceed further until **ArrayStoreException** get handled. I want to do the following task by using **java.util.Arrays** & **Arrays.fill**. Don't suggest another way. Just want to resolve this.  Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance....

```
package PlayWithStars;    
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Monster {
    static char battleBoard[][] = new char[10][10];

    public void buildBattleBoard()  {
        for (char[] row : battleBoard)    {
            Arrays.fill(battleBoard,'*');
        }
    }

    public void redrawBoard() {               
        for (int k=1 ; k<=30 ; k++) {         // 
            System.out.print("-");            // to print  ------------------
        }                                     //

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < battleBoard.length; i++) {           
            for (int j = 0; j < battleBoard[i].length; j++) {   
                System.out.println("|"+battleBoard[i][j]+"|");   
            }                                                    
            System.out.println("");                           


        for (int k=1 ; k<=30 ; k++) {        //
            System.out.print("-");           // to print  ------------------
        }                                    //
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Monster m = new Monster();
        m.buildBattleBoard();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add stack trace for the error you get.

Comment: Arrays.fill(battleBoard,'*'); should be Arrays.fill(row,'*');
and redraw() is not at all called

Answer (score 5):

in `buildBattleBoard()`,
`Arrays.fill(battleBoard,'*');` should be `Arrays.fill(row,'*');`. You forgot to reference the array in the for-each loop.

The compiler is using the `Arrays.fill( Object[] , Object);` method instead of the `Arrays.fill( char[] , char);`, hence no errors during compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Array.fill expects a dimensional array and you are providing nothing.

```
int i=0;
    for (char[] row : battleBoard)    {
           Arrays.fill(battleBoard[i],'*');
           i++;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.fill(battleBoard, '*');
```

Replace the above line of code by:

```
Arrays.fill(row, '*');
```

And everything will work as expected.